# Exposing Kafka metrics to Prometheus and Grafana on Rancher

Tags: apache-kafka, grafana, prometheus, rancher, strimzi

I have Strimzi Operator deployed on my Rancher Kuberenetes environment running on AWS. I used teh Strimzi operator to deploy my Kafka cluster with 3 brokers.  My cluster is running fine and I can produce and consume. Now i want to monitor the Kafka cluster using Prometheus and Grafana. I am using version 2.2.6 of Rancher so that comes with Prometheus and Grafana and I want to use that for monitoring.

I tried the documenation on Strimzi Operator but could not get the metrics as provided on the documentation. My Grafana dashboard is showing NA or 0. In fact teh namespace where my Kafka cluster is running is also not showing u. Can you please provide help with how to setup the metrics reporting of Kafka cluster using the inbuilt Prometheus and Grafana in Rancher?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could add comments.

You are probably missing `ServiceMonitor`.
If you proivde output from:

```
kubectl get servicemonitors.monitoring.coreos.com --all-namespaces
kubectl get prometheus -o yaml --all-namespaces
kubectl get svc --show-labels
```

I think I can help you.
(I will edit this answer later)